# SQL Database Parent/Children which one should I auto increment

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, relational-database, primary-key

I have two tables in a SQL database:

```
Underwriters
Brokers
```

`Underwriters` can have many brokers and `Brokers` can have many underwriters.

I created an intermediary table called `UnderwritersBrokers` and I have an `ID` in that table that is linked via a one to many relation to each of the other tables.

I want to auto increment the record ID each time I enter a new record. which table would I set the auto increment on, the child tables or the parent (intermediary)

I apologise for being a novice, this is all new to me and I just cant get my head around it.

Thanks in advance for clearing this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `auto_increment` in all three!

In particular, you want to use `auto_increment` in both the `Underwriters` and `Brokers` tables.  This will give you, respectively, a unique `UnderwriterId` for each underwriter and a unique `BrokerId` for each broker.

The junction table should then use these ids.  The junction table can also have its own id.  I would add one there, but a unique id in a junction table is less important than in the entity tables.